# Storing a variable name in a variable in batch file

Tags: batch-file

I'm creating a script that I can use to set up new user account in AD.

Early in the batch file I have a variable that is saved like this -

```
set state=%pspath% "St" -Value 'Gloucestershire'
```

pspath is populated later in the batch when the user is actually being created this part -

```
set pspath="Set-ItemProperty -Path 'CN=%firstname% %lastname%,%ou%' -Name"
powershell -nologo Import-Module ActiveDirectory;Set-Location AD:;%state%;
```

Firstname, lastname and ou is all populated without a problem, but in that second line when I'm using the %state% variable, %pspath% is ignore and the command comes out as

```
powershell -nologo Import-Module ActiveDirectory;Set-Location AD:;"St" -Value 'Gloucestershire'
```

instead of what it should be -

```
powershell -nologo Import-Module ActiveDirectory;Set-Location AD:;Set-ItemProperty -Path 'CN=%firstname% %lastname%,%ou%' -Name "St" -Value 'Gloucestershire'
```

How do I get all the variables to populate in the command properly instead of %pspath% being skipped?

Comment: You could just use a powershell script, instead of trying to run powershell.exe commands from the cmd.exe; this idea is just crazy.